# What is an effective strategy to win in Bloons TD Battles?

Tags: bloons-td-battles

I've been playing Bloons TD Battles a lot recently because of the pandemic but keep losing. Is there any way I can win while wasting as little time as possible (so I can play more games)? Here are my available towers: Dart Monkey, Tack Shooter, Ninja Monkey, Bomb Shooter, Mortar Tower, Sniper Monkey, Glue Gunner, Monkey Ace, Dartling Gunner, Spike Factory, Monkey Buccaneer, Boomerang Monkey, and Ice Tower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a Ninja Monkey. Get more Ninjas but upgrade to 2/1 if you need to.
Then wait to get a Bomb Tower and upgrade to 0/1 for grouped bloons and/or a 1/2 Sniper Monkey for camo leads.
Save up money (don't send bloons), unless you have a little money left.
I also recommend putting a Spike Factory at the end of the track, so it can build up spikes and when the bloons get too far the spikes will slow them down, slowly upgrade these.

Hope this helps a little!

Comment: My own strategy is better than this but it is pretty good. Thanks!

Comment: also its called spike factory, not tack shooter

Comment: Ah, sorry. I get those mixed up. Also what's your strategy? I would liek to try it!

Comment: mine is different for every map but my main strategy is to put some 3/2 boomerangs and a 2/3 ninja or 2 2/3 buccaneers for camo leads. then at round 12 check if the opponent has camo lead detection. if not, rush with camo leads and win. if so, wait until round 13 and rush with grouped regen rainbows and hope to win. if your opponent can defend, then you just gotta try to survive as long as possible and maybe send a few zomgs if you can.

Comment: Doesn't seem to bad. I'll have to try that!

Comment: yay i have 23 rep. now so i can vote yours up :D